How can I compile with only llvm?
I'm trying to compile things using llvm only, but came into many problems.
In order not to miss a single feature of LLVM, I tried to compile the whold llvm-project according to the commands in this post, enabling EH and RTTI and assertion, and inclduing libcxx and libc. The build terminates normally without any error, so I ran cmake install and archieved the output and put them into a folder toolchain.
Then I started a sample project containing only a hello world main.cpp. I order to use LLVM, I added -nostdc++ -nostdc option, and included include/c++/v1 directory, so the final compile commands is like this:
/home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/bin/clang-19 --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  -isystem /home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/include -isystem /home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/include/c++/v1 -isystem /home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/c++/v1 -g -std=gnu++11 -nostdinc -nostdinc++ -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src/test.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src/test.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/src/test.cpp.o -c /home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/src/test.cpp

but this won't work:
/home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/include/c++/v1/__configuration/platform.h:35:12: fatal error: 'features.h' file not found
   35 | #  include <features.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


I then searched for features.h, I found them in
/usr/include/c++/13/parallel/features.h
/usr/include/features.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/platform/features.h

and usr/include/features.h further includes bits/wordsize.h. I wonder whether I have to include /usr/include which contains many files I don't need, is there a way to compile only using llvm?

No, any compiler will need to use system headers to interact with the operating system

@AlanBirtles what's the minimum set of system headers to include? There're so many header files in /usr/include, and I'm not sure if there'll be conflicts if I include both libcxx and /usr/include

I don't think there is any minimum set of required headers. You can always try to compile something like int main(){}. However, I don't understand your question. You say that you have a "hello world" program. How can you write such a program without including some header file?

I'm general you shouldn't need to do anything, clang works out for itself which directories to include. clang++ -stdlib=libc++ should just work with no additional flags

@DanielLangr Actually I included , that's why I need to compile llvm's libcxx as well and trying to introduce it with -isystem.

@AlanBirtles But I need to explicitly tell clang to use the libs and libcxx headers under ${projectDir}/toolchain/llvm

you shouldn't need to, if they were compiled and installed together, their path should be hard coded into clang

I've solved the problem myself.
The problem is caused by the wrong -isystem directories. I should include ${TOOLCHAIN_LLVM_DIR}/lib/clang/${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}/include instead of /usr/include/linux. In the stddef.h located in the former directory, several basic types such as ptrdiff_t is defined, and both the two directories contains stdc headers stddef.h.

I believe you shouldn't manually -isystem that directory. You should do -resource-dir=${TOOLCHAIN_LLVM_DIR}/lib/clang/${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}. I'm surprised it didn't work for you out of the box though. Can you run clang -print-resource-dir to see the default value?

@HolyBlackCat I'm guessing they've left out the crucial detail that they've moved everything from the original install directory to somewhere else

@AlanBirtles I was under impression that it looks relative to the clang executable. So maybe they moved just that. D:

@HolyBlackCat ./toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/bin/clang++ -print-resource-dir outputs /home/nekomiya/.vs/kits/toolchain/x86_64-linux/llvm/19.1.1/lib/clang/19, seems nothing wrong? In fact -isystem is added by CMake's include_directory(SYSTEM ...), and I'm verifying the build commands in shell manually. But if I change from -isystem to resource-dir, fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found is reported again.

I've moved everything from the original install directory to somewhere else, as @AlanBirtles said, but I'm not aware of the impact of this move, does it has some impacts on the compilation process? My purpose is to build up a portable toolchain set, am I going into some wrong way?

(Here everything means the whole llvm-install folder)
